# Laravel 5.2 Model User->Invoice->InvoiceDetails

Tags: php, relationship, laravel-5

I have 3 models and i don't know which relationship do i need to write for each model

User   |   Invoice   |   InvoiceDetails

A User can have many Invoices and one Invoice is made by only one User.
So in User Class i write:

```
public function invoice(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice');
}
```

and inside Invoice Class i write:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Is this ^ correct?

And now, one Invoice has one InvoiceDetail does that mean for each Invoice there is only one row in table invoice_details?

I just don't know what to write inside each model, how to connect them?
I have made a little schema just to show what it should be like:
[image]

So the question is, which functions to write inside each Model to declare proper connections between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've written so far is fine, it links users to invoices properly (almost). The only thing is you need to rename `owner_id` to `user_id`, or specify that it should use the `owner_id` field.

**User class**

```
// Note that the function should be plural as it's for many
public function invoices(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice', 'owner_id', 'ID');
}
```

**Invoice class**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'ID', 'owener_id');
}
```

Then you just need to define the relationship with InvoiceDetails

**Invoice class**

```
public function invoiceDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\InvoiceDetails');
}
```

**InvoiceDetails class**

```
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
}
```

Comment: So i need to specifically set 'owner_id' <=> 'ID' ?

Comment: Yes, because by default larval will try to use the name of the table, in this case `user_id`, it also uses lower case for `id`.  It's good practise to use what laravel is expecting.